# Reopen question on "Senior managers dont promote internally"

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-request

I don't understand how you can flag this as opinion-based when the question's text EXPLICITLY asks if it's a common occurrence or not.

I would like the discussion to continue, please reopen the [question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/108036/senior-managers-dont-promote-internally-but-hire-their-old-team-is-this-expect).

Comment: We prefer questions that have practical answers over this kind of general "*is X common?*". What if we told you it was? Would that change anything about your situation? A better question here would be something akin to "*How do I gain visibility / get promoted in a culture doing X*". And if you're that adamant about the start-up aspect, [startups.se] *might* be a better fit, though I don't know if your question is on-topic there. And note that this is a Q&A site not a forum: there is no discussion that should be taking place there...

Comment: Terrible, no other comment to make. Enjoy yourself.

Comment: @Monoandale if you wish to engage in a more open discussion perhaps you can try that on [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3060/the-water-cooler). There you can surely get "answers" to more open "questions" like *Is this common*

Comment: @Monoandale umm it was actually a real piece of advice, as the Watercooler is usually active. There we can discuss this thoroughly if you wish to, no sarcasm intended

Comment: @Monoandale yes, please come to chat.  We have cookies

Comment: @Lilienthal: Care to make that into a regular answer? I´d like to up vote it?

Comment: @Daniel No real need I think. Meta is more discussion-focussed and the answer vs comment distinction is less relevant. We also don't clean-up comments here the way we do on main. And my comment is also less of an answer and was more intended to point out some potential improvements.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

No need to reopen, it already has a perfectly good answer.

Comment: "Closed" Status should not be abused to protect from further answers. *IF* it is a good Q/A that is worth having on the site, it should not be closed.